# Create new list containing only unique values from original list

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, unique

I have a function that finds the unique values of a list, but I can't create a new list with them.

```
import numpy as np
def unique(list): 
    x = np.array(list) 
    print(np.unique(x))

list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]  
unique(list1)
```

My output are the unique values but I want to create a new list containing them. I thought it would be as simple as bellow but when I print list2 the output says "None". I feel there is a really easy answer but I can't figure it out.

```
list2 = unique(list1) 
print(list2)
```

Comment: Your function returns `None` implicitly because you never return anything explicitly

Comment: Why do you need `numpy` for this? You can simply do `list1 = list(set(list1))`.

Comment: @eloen please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The result of the function must be returned.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
def unique(list):
    x = np.array(list)
    x = np.unique(x)
    return x

list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]
new_list = unique(list1)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I looked for

Comment: You're welcome @eloen

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter you can use `set` to remove dupes and then back to a `list`:

```
list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]
list1 = list(set(list1))
list1
[40, 10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's problem at all, they already have a method to get unique values anyway, showing them another method doesn't address the fundamental issue of their function not returning anything. If they were asking how to remove duplicates from a list it would be a duplicate anyway

Comment: Thanks this is much simpler and order dosn't matter.